# How is cross-attention different when you interchange the queries and keys/values?

Tags: attention

In the Facebook Paper about Segment Anything, (https://scontent-atl3-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.2365-6/10000000_6331779526880473_6748528980292947838_n.pdf?_nc_cat=102&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=3c67a6&_nc_ohc=lnYqcLNTtLQAX82Bb1_&_nc_ht=scontent-atl3-2.xx&oh=00_AfCJdEQrYLMaz-qmfUh53sxq7UpddM1_TxvIUFyoT91Oig&oe=6432ACEA)

they have in Page 16 this image:

[image]

Where there are two parts: one  where tokens are used as queries in a cross attention, and another where the images are used as the queries in cross attention. The paper authors say:

> Our decoder design is shown in Fig. 14. Each decoder
> layer performs 4 steps: (1) self-attention on the tokens, (2)
> cross-attention from tokens (as queries) to the image embedding, (3) a point-wise MLP updates each token, and (4)
> cross-attention from the image embedding (as queries) to
> tokens. **This last step updates the image embedding with
> prompt information.**

I'm not clear why the last step is needed. Won't step (2) in which cross attention is performed between tokens and image embeddings suffice? How does cross-attention change when you use the image embeddings as queries or vice versa?